Como rotar una imagen en css?
Este es mi codigo y estoy usando una imagen de fondo que esta vertical y la quiero poner en horizontal rotandola en css:
body {
    background-image: url("../IMG/prueba4.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}



Hay un estilo llamado rotate. Pruébalo. Tal vez quiera aplicar la imagen sobre otro elemento ya que rotate rota el elemento, no solo el background

No es posible rotar una imagen de fondo, lo que si puedes hacer es usar un pseudo elemento con el fondo y rotar este pseudolemento


.confondo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.confondo:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);
  z-index: -1;
}
.confondo.rotate:before{
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
<div class="confondo">Sin rotar</div>
<div class="confondo rotate">Rotado</div>



No obstante, mi concejo es que si es posible, lo mejor es editar la imagen usando tu editor favorito (photoshopt, gimp, paint, paint.net, etc) y rotarla directamente
